# Automate Azure Portal Flows for Authenticated Users only

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-automation

I am searching for a way to automate Microsoft Azure management flows, like creating machines and disabling users.

Automation Account is a little too slow for me, it can take up to 30 minutes for a runbook to run - and I want to have the response immediately.
Azure functions are much faster but have not User context. I want them to be able to work only with users having the right permissions.

Is there another way? Can I make Azure Functions aware of Azure Portal Permission and AD Groups?

Comment: have you check the picture I post? and if it helps, would you mind accept my reply as answer for others to refer? @thecohenoam

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can do that. Here is an example (HttpTriggered) which makes the right user trigger your function but deny others:

1. Navigate to your function app in portal, click `Authentication/authorization`, configure `login with Azure AD`.
   [image]
2. Navigate to Azure Active Directory, click manifest, configure `appRoles`.
   [image]
3. Go back to the overview of AAD, and go to `Managed application in...`.
   [image]
4. Click Users and groups in the left panel, click `+Add User`, you can add users and groups to Role assigned we added in manifest file before.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmvA2.jpg)
5. Click Properties in the left panel, configure `User assignment required?` to `Yes`.
   [image]
   You can test with rest api like this:
6. Acquire access token
   [image]
7. Access your function with request header `Authorization`.
   [image]

Comment: For some reason the Authentication/authorization blade is disabled in my function app settings

Comment: Maybe you should check if your account have the permission for assignment in Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal

Comment: I am a Global Administrator

Comment: Is your Global Admin set under Active assignment? https://i.stack.imgur.com/61c8P.png